# Sending http requests to localhost by PHP

Tags: apache, http, server, request

I have installed two PHP Frameworks on one server (TYPO3 and CakePHP). The TYPO3 Websites sends http requests (API) to CakePHP. My hoster says that this is bad practice and crashes the server (Mittwald) from time to time.

What do you think? Is this a bad practice or is it bad hosting? What would be a common way?

Thank you

Comment: If that server crashes, then it is of _very_ bad quality, since a request to the local system is a normal http request.

Comment: You definitely should ask for much more detailed information what your provider actually means by that. _Why_ the http server crashes.

Comment: The provider said, that the number of "self request" is much to high and that it is very uncommon to send http requests to localhost.
I'm confused - is it really bad to send http requests to localhost or is it just an alibi from the hoster?

Comment: It is not per definition bad, nor is it uncommon. Certainly there might be alternatives, but the question remains: how can such requests _crash_ a server? At most it should slow it down, if you really make many many requests per second. Like a system getting unresponsive in a DOS attack. So what you can do on your side is answer these two questions: 1. how many such requests _are_ actually done and 2. if that is a significant number, how can it be reduced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I second the opinion of your hoster.

In case every page view in TYPO3 cause a call to CakePHP, this is bad practice because you need the bootstrap process of two systems and you also require a lot processing time. TYPO3 hast to wait for the return value of CakePHP, which means both system consume memory at the same time.

In case you call CakePHP from TYPO3 in an asynchronous way as a scheduled task, you might consider using direct database access instead of API calls, because it uses less memory after all.

After all you have to decide yourself, if you want to invest time for a solution which consumes less resources of if you pay more to get more resources.

Comment: Thank you - we have "solved" it for the moment by requesting data by Shell commands so there are no http requests anymore.